# Android: Scope of onActivityResult()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, scope

I observed an unexpected behaviour with `onActivityResult()` in the following situation:

**1.) MainActivity has an `onActivityResult()` method and adds `RecipeFragment`**.

```
Fragment fragment = new RecipeFragment(recipeBo);
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, FragmentTag.RECIPE.toString())
.addToBackStack(FragmentTag.RECIPE.toString())
.commit();
```

**2.) RecipeFragment has an `onActivityResult()` method and starts `RecipeEditMenuPopupActivity`**.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeEditMenuPopupActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.MENU_RECIPEMODIFICATION_POPUP.ordinal());
```

**3.) `RecipeEditMenuPopupActivity()` starts `ConfirmActivity` and `ConfirmActivity` sends the result back to `RecipeFragment`**.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

**4.) `RecipeFragment's` `onActivityResult()` receives the result, which was expected by me, but also `MainActivity's` `onActivityResult()` receives the result which I didn't expect.**

Basically this is no problem, but I'd like to understand what the scope of `onActivityResult()` is. Due to this example it is obvious that Activities and its members (like fragments) share the scope. But do non-members also receive the messages and where are the restrictions if there are any?

Comment: The `Activity` handles delivering results to its `Fragment`s, which is why its `onActivityResult()` method gets called, and also why you need to call through to the `super` method there. Nothing outside of the `Activity` is going to get it.

Comment: @tynn I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Well @MikeM., only the `FragmentActivity` implementation delegates `onActivityResult()` to a `Fragment`. The implementation of `Activity.onActivityResult()` has an empty body, so how is this working without using `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Ok, I found the implmentation for this in `Activity.dispatchActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is an implementation detail only connected to `Fragment`. When calling `startActivityForResult()` from a fragment, the activity remembers to notify it later.

In the pure Android [`Activity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) this notification is done within `dispatchActivityResult()` and therefore, before `onActivityResult()` of the activity itself is called. So you'll only receive the result once.

In the support [`FragmentActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java) you find an implementation of `onActivityResult()` passing the result to a `SupportFragment`. To find this fragment, the higher 16 bit of `requestCode` are use and that's why you find an `IllegalArgumentException`

> Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

sometimes when calling `startActivityForResult()`.